# Audio playback (file located on the internet) with kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm practicing with MediaPlayer and my problem is the moment I press the button, I don't hear the sound and the application crashes.

add this in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

My code

```
button1.setOnClickListener {
            val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/recursos/gato.mp3")
                mediaPlayer.prepare()
                mediaPlayer.start()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No existe el archivo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        }
```

Comment: Post the crash log please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1
add this in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

located the (<aplication) and within  add that:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Press alt + control about it and select (Suppress with tools:targetApi attributes

Step 2
below the class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
Create a private val

```
private val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
```

Finaly delete

```
val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
```

Answer (score 0):

Read mediaplayer documentation.
Don't initialize mediaplayer with :

```
MediaPlayer()
```

You need to create it with :

```
MediaPlayer.create(context,uri)
```

So pass context as first parameter and your url as uri with this :

```
Uri.parse("YOUR_URL")
```

Comment: Could be more specific, I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0):

You can make:

```
button1.setOnClickListener {
            val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/recursos/gato.mp3")
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener {
                        mediaPlayer.start()
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No existe el archivo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        }
```

And you need add permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: The application does not crash but still cannot hear the sound

Comment: Maybe you need reinstall app, because it work fine.